# replacing the phone number with asterisks

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

How can I show only the first 4 digits of a number and cover all the other digits with asterisks? knowing that Numbers may have different lengths

I must be doing something wrong, I need to show only the first 4 digits:

```
var test = '447537126710' // 12 number 15 number phone
//I want to do this: 4475*********
```

My script replaces only the first digits, but I need to replace different lengths and the last digits

Comment: It shouldn't be that hard. *My script replaces only the first digits*, maybe share your attempt here?

Comment: @HaoWu, `test.replace(/^([\w]|.{4})/, '*')`

Comment: Maybe try `test.replace(/^(.{4})|./g, (_, start) => start || '*')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use substring and then replace rest of the characters

```js
var test = '447537126710';
const num = test.substr(0, 4) +
  test.substr(4, test.length).replace(/[0-9]/g, '*')
console.log(num)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [lookbehind assertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#other_assertions) to only match digits that are preceded by (at least) 4 other digits:

```js
const test = '447537126710';
console.log( test.replace(/(?<=\d{4})\d/g, '*') )
```

Comment: It is discouraged to use lookbehinds since Safari and iOS devices will throw an error. But node.js is okay.